# How does a parent subscribe to SpeedChanged event of a child component?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I  have a child component called `Earth` as follows.

```
<h3>Earth's speed is @Speed unit.</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter] public double Speed { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<double> SpeedChanged { get; set; }
}
```

A parent component called `God` consumes the `Earth` as follows.

```
@page "/God"

<Earth @bind-Speed="speed" SpeedChanged="Job" />

<button @onclick="@(()=>speed=0)">Stop Spinning!</button>

@code {
    private double speed = 100.0;
    private void Job(double s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Earth's speed: {s}");
    }
}
```

Here I am attempting to subscribe to `SpeedChanged` of the `Earth` component via

```
<Earth @bind-Speed="speed" SpeedChanged="Job" />
```

Unfortunately, I got the following errors on the Visual Studio:

> The component parameter `SpeedChanged` is used two or more times for
> this component. Parameters must be unique (case-sensitive). ...

How to fix this issue? Any ideas are welcome!

## Edit

From MS documentation, I understood that

```
<Earth @bind-Speed="speed" />
```

is equivalent to

```
<Earth @bind-Speed="speed" @bind-Speed:event="SpeedChanged" />
```

Comment: This is because `@bind-Speed` automatically looks for and hooks up `SpeedChanged`. If you want to do this manually, try this `<Earth Speed="speed" SpeedChanged="Job" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement component data-binding, you should define two parameter properties, as you really do:

```
[Parameter] public double Speed { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<double> SpeedChanged { get; set; }
```

To bind this child component to the parent component's property, you do the following:

```
<Earth @bind-Speed="speed"/>
```

This creates a two-way data-binding between the parent and child components.

Note: You do not provide a value for the SpeedChanged property. It is implied, which is why you get an error when you try to do so, as the compiler is going to do it herself. The compiler insert code that do the binding from child to parent.

> From MS documentation, I understood that

```
<Earth @bind-Speed="speed" />
```

is equivalent to

```
<Earth @bind-Speed="speed" @bind-Speed:event="SpeedChanged" />
```

That's true, but you were doing something else... As I've said the compiler was going to add the SpeedChanged...now, if you try to add it manually, it is as though you were using it twice...not allowed.

When you create a two-way data-binding between an input element and a property like this:

```
<input type="text" @bind="MyProperty"/>
```

The compiler, behind the scenes creates the binding as if you wrote:

```
<input type="text" value="MyProperty" @onchange="@((args)=>MyProperty=args.Value.ToString())"/>
```

Now, if you wrote something like `<input type="text" @bind="MyProperty" @onchange="....."/>`, the compiler will start screaming that onchange is already used. The same thing that happens with your code.

Comment: It is true. As a result, `public EventCallback<double> SpeedChanged { get; set; }` should be set `private` so the "client" cannot access it. It is a design issue.

Comment: You know what ? We previously had to define the property as private, but current Blazor design requires you to define properties as public...

Comment: A nice info. Thank you!